# How to capitalize first letter in Google Tag Manager Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

SO I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of my string and make the rest lower for a GTM JavaScrip Macro variable.

But it doesn't work. When testing on normal HTML page it does work.

My code:

```js
function() {
  var categoryUpper = {{Click Text}};
  
  function firstLetterCapital(cat) {
    return cat.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cat.slice(1);
  }

  return firstLetterCapital(categoryUpper);
}
```

Does anyone know how to capitalize first letter in GTM variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
  var txt = {{Click Text}};
  return txt.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(t){
    return t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah yes this works! However I found out I shouldn't use it in the JavaScript Macro Variable, but I should run it in the HTML tag. Then it works. Thanks!